# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, token

I have the following script, which returns me the following error in my console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }..

The `}` in between `**` is the one causing the problem according to my console. But that's the bracket which closes the 'success' of the AJAX request.. And also if i remove the statement pointed out with the -> the error seems to disappear. Does someone see what is wrong about this?

Note: I don't have those `**` in my code, that's just for pointing out the error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#edit_patient_info').click(function () {
                //Get the data from all the fields

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "patient_info_controller.php", 
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,     
                        success: function (msg) {
                            if (msg==1) {             
                                getPersoonlijkGegevens(user_id);
                                unLockFirstPage();
                                alert("Gegevens zijn gewijzigd!");
                                $("#searchbox").val(voornaam.val());
                                searchPatient();
                          ->    $('#selectable li:first').addClass('ui-selected');​
                            }
                        **}**       
                    });
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had a hidden character after `$('#selectable li:first').addClass('ui-selected');`

That invalidated your code. Usually, these can be seen when you copy your code to notepad (Or notepad++).
In notepad++, it displayed `.addClass('ui-selected');?`

Also, you had a extra `}`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit_patient_info').click(function () {
        //Get the data from all the fields

        $.ajax({
            url: "patient_info_controller.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: data,     
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg==1) {             
                    getPersoonlijkGegevens(user_id);
                    unLockFirstPage();
                    alert("Gegevens zijn gewijzigd!");
                    $("#searchbox").val(voornaam.val());
                    searchPatient();
                    $('#selectable li:first').addClass('ui-selected');
                }
            }      
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's still got a syntax error; you need a `);` after that second to last `}` to complete the `.click()` function call. You've essentially done what I said in my answer, which you seem to think is wrong.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: should be fixed now, not? You made no mention of the hidden character messing up his code.

Comment: That's because the hidden character wasn't visible in the question, and there was no reason for me to suspect one was there because there was an immediately obvious problem for the error being reported: the extra, unnecessary `}`. If he'd fixed that he would have been informed of the extra character by his debugging tool.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` is the only error you will ever get from that character, from some JS validators.

Comment: The problem was the hidden character. I have re-written everything and the problem is solved now, thank guys.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it's actually the `}` two lines down from the one you've marked that's causing the issues; it doesn't match up with any of the opening `{` characters.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, it is. He has a `}` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: The } was there, because I had an if statement before the ajax request. I scrapped the if statement to keep this code sample short.

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra }

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit_patient_info').click(function() {
    //Get the data from all the fields
    $.ajax({
        url: "patient_info_controller.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg == 1) {
                getPersoonlijkGegevens(user_id);
                unLockFirstPage();
                alert("Gegevens zijn gewijzigd!");
                $("#searchbox").val(voornaam.val());

            }
        }
    });
  });
});​
```